# Synonyms for "doing one's best"

Tags: synonyms

Is there a more formal synonym for "doing one's best"?

For example, as a formal document title: "Is the government [doing its best] to..."

Or is it suitable (i.e., sufficiently formal) as it is?

Comment: Define *formal*. It's unclear what you're asking, and the question sounds primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "striving". This implies "doing one's best".

Comment: I have a problem with "striving", (call it a hangup, actually.)  To me "strive" and "endeavor", etc., sound like an effort is being made but does not take my confidence to a level of ultimate, leave-it-all-on-the-stage, drop-dead best work. (But that's just me!) :-)

Comment: This made me giggle. I suppose you could be working very hard (aka "striving"), yet not doing your very best.

Comment: Maybe a regional difference or something, but "strive" sounds way more take-my-confidence-to-a-level-of-etc to my ears. "doing one's best" seems like doing 100%; "striving" seems like attempting to go for 132% (however futile that may be)....

Comment: I think "strive" is the strongest word and it fits more in formal contexts.

Answer (score 2):

**Endeavor**  may be a good option to use for the phrase "doing one's best".

> [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/endeavor): Try hard to do or achieve something

Example sentence: We always endeavor to please our customers.

Answer (score 0):

For a sense of "best effort" in a title, you can say,

> ***"Is the Government Pulling Out All the Stops to...?"***
>
> ***"Did the Government Take it to the Nth Degree to...?"***
>
> ***"Is the Government Going to Heroic Efforts to...?"***

Answer (score 0):

'give full measure', 'give one's best', 'go all out' are some of the synonyms of 'doing one's best'.

Answer (score -1):

You could also express this as:

> Could the government do more to ... ?